# Размер (физический) таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, innodb, mysql-5.7

Товарищи, возник любопытный вопрос, может кто-нибудь подскажет ответ.

*Предыстория: имеется приличных размеров табличка, основную часть данных занимает один JSON столбец. Надо как-то подужать место, так что провожу некоторые "исследования".*

Развернул локально фрагмент таблицы на ~1.3млн строк.
Имеем следующую структуру таблицы (`InnoDB,row_format=DYNAMIC`):

```
a BIGINT,
b BIGINT,
c TINYINT,
d JSON NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (a,b,c)
```

Занимает это добро **5.8Гбайт** на диске (все JSON поля непустые).

- Если просуммировать `JSON_STORAGE_SIZE(d)` то получим **~3.5Гбайт**.
- Мы так же можем предположить и объем требуемый на `a,b,c = (8+8+1)*1300000/1024/1024` **~20мбайт**

разница в **2Гб** между "теоретическим" и практическим размером выглядит приличной.

Для эксперимента сделал две таблицы:

- `(a,b,c)` та же таблица без json-столбца. Размер **48мбайт**
- `(i,d)`, где i - `INT AUTO_INCREMENT` (то есть упростил ключ до целого) - размер **4.8Гбайт**.

Тут получается суммарный размер двух этих таблиц на *1ГБайт* меньше исходной (хотя фактически  к данным добавили `INT` столбец).

Может кто нибудь объяснить чем вызвана такая разница в объемах?

*зы: если вдруг интересно, то `row_format=compressed` делает из исходной 5.8 -> 2.4*

*зы2: таблицы только созданные. То есть созданы и влиты данные. никаких удалений/апдейтов не проводилось*

Чую ответ будет включать что-нибудь про кластеризацию, страницы, и т.п. но не силен в механике физического хранения.

Comment: А у вас часто в таблице изменяются уже существующие записи или удаляются какие либо записи ? При обновлении записи, если она перестает влезать в страницу где она лежала, ее перенесут в другое место. А то место, что она занимала останется свободным и когда будет чем то еще занято не известно. То же и при удалении записей, остаются куски не используемого пространства

Comment: @Mike это понятно, что при удалении место остается занятым. Тут пока что речь идет о свежих таблицах, на которых ничего не удалялось и не изменялось.

Comment: Записи при загрузке отсортированы в одном и том же порядке ? Для чистоты эксперимента стоит грузить данные в порядке первичного ключа. Если порядок вставки был разным, то из за необходимости перебалансировки дерева могут появляться пустые страницы. Хотя потери 1 Гб при ребалансировке кажутся согромными. Видимо еще что то, о чем не могу предполагать

Comment: Предлагаю в целях эксперимента сравнить размеры при загрузке одних данных в том же порядке вообще без первичного ключа или в обоих случаях использовать автоинкремент (даже если для этого придется добавить лишний столбец

Comment: @Mike аххах, ларчик просто открывался, вы правы ) порядок вставки в первую таблицу был примерно обратным (`a desc, b, c`, ибо был экспорт последних 2млн строк из рабочей бызы). А копирование во вторую уже из первой, формально без сортировки, так что по сути прямой (`a asc,b,c`). Ребилд основной таблицы свел ее к 4.9Гб. Оформите ответом, мб добавив еще чего  нить полезного на тему. спасибо! )

Comment: если кстати брать средние размеры объектов, которые хранятся, то минимальная длина 70байт, максимум 40кбайт. В среднем 2830байт. Наиболее частый тип объекта (1млн из 1.3 строк)  от 1600 до 4300 байт, в среднем 2520. Так-то они хранятся вне страниц, сами страницы только указатель должны содержать, но как именно я хз. Так то размер пустот тоже зависит от среднего размера объекта, надо полагать.

Comment: Есть такой параметр: [fill factor](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_fill_factor). Он может сильно влиять, в зависимости от заданного значения. Но по умолчанию данные должны плотно паковаться. / [The Physical Structure of an InnoDB Index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-physical-structure.html) - здесь написано, что при вставке в случайном порядке страницы могут лишь наполовину заполняться.

Comment: А по поводу "подужать место", есть у меня подобная таблица. В моем случае json был всего с двумя уровнями вложенности  и в нем было ограниченное множество ключей. При этом имена ключей имели очень большую длину (например "cash_oper_activities_net"). Я создал отдельный словарь в котором всем возможным именам ключей json дал двух-трех буквенные коды. В хранимом в БД json все данные лежат с короткими именами ключей, при поднятии записей из БД перед отдачей клиенту имена транслируются в понятные ему (словарь преобразования удерживается в памяти)

Comment: @Mike да, над ужатием самого контента сейчас тоже работаем, удаляем избыточные для нас данные, которые без особых трудозатраn можно грохнуть. тестовая таблица собственно в половину уменьшается в размере.

Comment: вообще есть вариант уйти от составного ключа к инкременту. Изначально составной был сделан чтобы обеспечить за счет кластеризации более быстрые чтения данных. А потом выделить JSON столбец в отдельную таблицу, которую вообще сделать `compressed`. В целом непосредственно в базе с контентом столбца не работает, только отдаем его на клиента. Когда таблицу создавали что-то не думали что она до полтерабайта дорастет.

Comment: вообще, кстати, частичный дамп был влит в таблицу 0, из нее уже указанные 4 столбца были перелиты в таблицу 1. странно. должно было быть в порядке ключа. странно, что место съел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В MySQL нет особенностей физического хранения, приводящих к существенно большему размеру данных из за сочетания разных типов колонок. Любые отличия размеров могут быть вызваны только остающимся в таблице не используемом пространстве. Свободное пространство остается при удалении и при перемещении записей на новое место.

Формат InnoDB подразумевает кластеризацию таблицы по первичному ключу. За термином "кластеризация" скрывается хранение всех данных в узлах индексного дерева. Для хранения строится индекс для первичного ключа и в него раскладываются данные. Близкие по значениям первичного ключа записи физически располагаются в одних страницах.

При загрузке данных в таблицу, если новые записи поступают в случайном порядке (относительно первичного ключа) MySQL требуется перемещать существующие записи на новое место, для вставки новых рядом с близкими им по ключу. Кроме того требуется более частая [балансировка дерева](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0#%D0%91%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0). Для уменьшения перемещения записей в процессе вставки MySQL резервирует в страницах пространство для будущих данных. При вставке в случайном порядке в блоках остается больше резервированных участков. Все это приводит к образованию большого количества не используемого пространства в таблице.

В ситуации описанной в вопросе, отличия в размерах таблиц вызваны не существенно большим полезных данных, а разными условиями вставки данных. В одном случае данные поступали хаотично относительно первичного ключа, в другом первичный ключ был основан на автоинкременте и рос монотонно. Что приводило к чрезмерным перемещениям данных в первом случае и гораздо меньше во втором.